# How to extract rows based on column's sequence of occurences

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract all the rows associated to their respective Ids that have 'In' in the type column that occured before 'Out' using the date column. In the data provided, only Id 1 & 2 would pass the test.
Test data is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
id INT,
[type] varchar(25),
[Dates] Date)

INSERT INTO #Table
VALUES (1, 'In', '2018-10-01'),
 (1, 'In', '2018-11-01'),
 (1, 'Out', '2018-12-01'),
 (2, 'In', '2018-10-01'),
 (2, 'Out', '2018-11-01'),
 (2, 'In', '2018-12-01'),
 (3, 'Out', '2018-10-01'),
 (3, 'In', '2018-11-01')
```

The ouput should look like that:

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | type |    date    |
+----+------+------------+
|  1 | In   | 2018-10-01 |
|  1 | In   | 2018-11-01 |
|  1 | Out  | 2018-12-01 |
|  2 | In   | 2018-10-01 |
|  2 | Out  | 2018-11-01 |
|  2 | In   | 2018-12-01 |
+----+------+------------+
```

Im honestly lost with querying this issue.
I started with

```
SELECT #Table.*, MIN(CASE WHEN #Table.[type] = 'In' THEN #Table.Dates ELSE NULL END) As A
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN #Table.[type] = 'Out' THEN #Table.Dates ELSE NULL END) As B
FROM #Table
GROUP BY #Table.id, #Table.[type], #Table.Dates
```

Not sure what to do from there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, aggregation and `having` do the trick:

```
select t.id
from #Table t
group by t.id
having min(case when type = 'In' then dates end) < max(case when type = 'Out' then dates end);
```

This selects `id`s where the earliest "in" is before the latest "out".

If you need the matching rows, you can use window functions, `in`, `exists` or a `join`:

```
select t.*
from #table t
where t.id in (select t2.id
               from #Table t2
               group by t2.id
               having min(case when t2.type = 'In' then t2.dates end) < max(case when t2.type = 'Out' then t2.dates end)
              );
```

Comment: I would need all its corresponding rows as well not just the Id @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 2):

This is Gordon's logic applied to your query using *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
with cte as 
 (
    SELECT #Table.*
        ,MIN(CASE WHEN #Table.[type] = 'In' THEN #Table.Dates ELSE NULL END)
         OVER(PARTITION BY id) As A -- min IN date per id
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN #Table.[type] = 'Out' THEN #Table.Dates ELSE NULL END)
         OVER(PARTITION BY id) As B -- max OUT date per id
    FROM #Table
 )
select *
from cte
where a < b
```

Of course can also use a subquery:

```
select *
from #Table
where id in 
 ( Gordon's Select )
```

Comment: im just unsure as to why we use MAX instead of MIN

Comment: It's your logic *'In' in the type column that occured before 'Out'* :-) You want rows where *MIN(IN-date)<MAX(OUT-date)*

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following using inner join as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (
id INT,
[type] varchar(25),
[Dates] Date)

INSERT INTO #Table
VALUES (1, 'In', '2018-10-01'),
 (1, 'In', '2018-11-01'),
 (1, 'Out', '2018-12-01'),
 (2, 'In', '2018-10-01'),
 (2, 'Out', '2018-11-01'),
 (2, 'In', '2018-12-01'),
 (3, 'Out', '2018-10-01'),
 (3, 'In', '2018-11-01')

 SELECT DISTINCT #Table.* FROM(
SELECT  * FROM #Table
)a inner join (
SELECT * FROM #Table
)b on a.id = b.id and a.Dates < b.Dates and a.[type] = 'In' and b.[type] = 'Out'
inner join #Table on a.id = #Table.id
```

You can see the below output as required

```
id  type    Dates
 --------------------
 1  In  2018-10-01
 1  In  2018-11-01
 1  Out 2018-12-01
 2  In  2018-10-01
 2  In  2018-12-01
 2  Out 2018-11-01
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you:

```
With CTE As
 (
   Select Id,[Type], [Dates], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By Id Order By Dates) As rn From #Tbl
 )
 Select * From cte
 Where cte.Id In (Select Distinct Id From CTE Where rn = 1 And [Type] = 'In')
```